# Am I right that $\arcsin(\sin(\theta))=\theta$ was incorrectly applied here?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

We need to find solution set for equation $\sin(x/4)=3/8$.
There is video with process of finding said solution set on Khan Academy, but I have problems with it. Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ES15mSuqHM8&t=51s

According to the video, one part of solution set can be found this way:

1. $\sin(\pi-\frac{x}{4}+2\pi n)=\frac{3}{8}$, where $n$ is any integer. We put both sides of the equation inside arcsine
2. $\arcsin(\sin(\pi-\frac{x}{4}+2\pi n))=\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})$. Here we apply theorem $\arcsin(\sin(θ))=θ$
3. $\pi-\frac{x}{4}+2\pi n=\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})$. Now let's rearrange letters to get expression equal to $x$.
4. $x=-4\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})+4\pi+8\pi n$

I see transition from step #2 to step #3 as problematic, because it is based on incorrect use of theorem $\arcsin(\sin(θ))=θ$. In order to get the same $θ$ both inside and the outside of $\sin()$, $θ$ must belong to range of $\arcsin()$, namely to closed interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$. But is it the case with "$\pi-\frac{x}{4}+2\pi n$"? I want to argue that no. This transformation must work for all values of $n$, thus it's enough to show single counterexample with any $n$ of our choosing, in order to show that the transformation is not correct. For sake of simplicity let's take $n=0$, thus we are left with "$\pi-\frac{x}{4}$".

We know that $\frac{x}{4}$ is an acute angle because $\arcsin(\sin(\frac{x}{4}))=\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})$ leads to
$x/4=\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})$. And here $\arcsin(\frac{3}{8})$ is equal to about $22$ degrees angle (I use degrees here only once, for sake of easy illustration of acuteness). So we have pi minus acute angle, which gives as the second quarter on the unit circle, which means that the angle "$\pi-x/4$" is more than $\pi/2$, which means that it's incorrect to use the theorem $\arcsin(\sin(θ))=θ$.

Comment: $$\sin(\theta)=s\iff \theta=\arcsin(s)+2k\pi\lor \theta=\pi-\arcsin(s)+2k\pi.$$

This is equivalent to

$$\arcsin(\sin(\theta))=\theta\iff \theta\in[-\tfrac\pi2,\tfrac\pi2].$$

Comment: @IAmAGuest Sorry, I don't understand how it answers my question

Comment: It does not, this is a comment.

Comment: @IAmAGuest Then I don't understand utility of said comment, how it helps

Comment: Could you please use MathJax when asking a question? See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You keep mentioning the "$\arcsin(\sin(\theta))=\theta$" theorem, but never state it !

Comment: @IAmAGuest You just stated it. The equation is the theorem, given that theta belongs to interval [-pi/2;pi/2]

Comment: But you never stated it explicitly.

Comment: What is $n$ exactly? Maybe it was choose so that $\pi - x/4 + 2n\pi$ is in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's incorrect. And uselessly complicated.

From $\sin(x/4)=3/8$ you simply get
$$
\frac{x}{4}=\arcsin(3/8)+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\frac{x}{4}=\pi-\arcsin(3/8)+2k\pi
$$
that yields
$$
x=4\arcsin(3/8)+8k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=4\pi-4\arcsin(3/8)+8k\pi
$$
No need to use $\arcsin(\sin(\theta))=\theta$, which is actually false unless, as you note, $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

---

If you have $a$ such that $-1< a< 1$, there are *two* angles in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ having sine equal to $a$: just intersect the unit circle with the line $y=a$. It's clear, geometrically, that one of the angles is in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and that the other one is the “supplementary” angle.

For $a=1$ or $a=-1$, the two families of solutions degenerate into one.

Comment: how did you get the second equation that starts with x/4=?

Comment: @user161005 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Solutions_to_elementary_trigonometric_equations .  I prefer the equivalent $\frac{x}{4}=(-1)^k\arcsin\left(\frac38\right)+k\pi.$ It's probably easiest to understand these general solutions by visualising the graph of the corresponding trigonometric function.

Comment: @RyanG I'm afraid your link only confuses me even more.

Comment: @user161005 It wasn't meant to be a full explanation, just a jumping-off point. The idea is that the trigonometric functions are cyclic and that given, say, $\sin \theta=0.375,$ we are able to generate all its infinitely many solutions: $\theta=k\pi+(-1)^k\arcsin0.375.$

Comment: @RyanG This form hides very well the fact that there are two families of solutions. In my opinion it's best to keep them separate.

Comment: @user161005 I added a short commentary.

Comment: I don't understand how you got $\frac{x}{4}=\arcsin(3/8)+2k\pi$ without using arcsin(sin(θ))=θ

Comment: @user161005 By definition of arcsine: $\arcsin y$ is the unique angle $x$ in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\sin x=y$. Of course also all angles differing from $x$ by a multiple of $2\pi$ will have the same sine. But there is another unique angle in the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ that has the same sine, so another family of solutions.